# Пустить запросы через proxy в telegram на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, proxy, requests

Есть следующий код для отправки сообщений в телеграм, но по причине блокировки, сообщения не идут, пытаюсь пустить все через прокси использую requests, но не особо получается, не понимаю куда пихать аргумент с прокси. Прошу помочь с решением.(код работает, пробовал запускать на амазоновском серваке, но перенести проект на какой либо сервер нельзя)

```
import requests
message="123456"

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://157.230.44.89:3128'

}

def send_telegram(text: str):
    token = "чччччччччччч"
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
channel_id = "@ччччччч"
    url += token
    method = url + "/sendMessage"
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://157.230.44.89:3128'
    }


    r = requests.post(method, data={
         "chat_id": channel_id,
         "text": text
          }, proxies=proxies)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("post_text error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  send_telegram(message)
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить прокси для https трафика. (proxies['https'] = 'http://157.230.44.89:1080')

Comment: @Evgeniy, спасибо, заработало!!!

Comment: добавил решение. если не сложно, тыкните галочку слева :)

Comment: @Evgeniy, не вопрос))) я 2 дня голову ломал))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить прокси для https трафика.

(`proxies['https'] = '157.230.44.89:1080'`)